# Zoom a selected rectangle region in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

In my d3 graph, i wanted to ZOOM a selected region.The region will be selected by drawing a rectangle on the required graph area.How can i achieve that in d3.js.

The graph already have default ZOOM feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the x and y domain according to the selected rectangle

https://gist.github.com/jasondavies/3689931